# Request Entity Too Large when data sent using AJAX

Tags: php

I am using the JavaScript canvas API `toDataURL()` to convert an image file to a base64 string and then transferring the string to my server via an XMLHttpRequest or simply an AJAX request. When I upload medium size files(500KB-1MB) I am getting the following error-

`413 Request Entity Too Large`

I have researched a lot. Tried changing `post_max_size`, `upload_max_size` but that didn't help. In an article it was suggested to set limit of the RequestBodyLength in Apache. But I couldn't find a way to do that!

Then I made a small hack and tried to upload the file by the old school method(iframe form upload) and it worked! Any help or suggestion on how to upload using the AJAX base64 string method would be awesome.

**EDIT- Here's the JavaScript codes that first converts the canvas element to base64 string and then uploads it to the server using AJAX.**

```
lab.newPost.submit = function(){
var url = 'upload.php';
var params = {
    'title': lab.newPost.elements.photo_form.title.val(),
    'imageData': Meme.canvas[0].toDataURL("image/jpeg"),  //Convert to Base64 data URL
    };

$.post(url,params, function(data){  //AJAX POST
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    if(data.success){
        Msg.success('<a href="#" class="alert-link">Awesome! </a> Thanks for contributing :)');
    }

    else{
      Msg.danger('<a href="#" class="alert-link">Error! </a>'+data.error[0]);
      }
    }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?
    console.log(thrownError);  //This line give 
    });
}
```

**The call returns the following lines-**

```
Request Entity Too Large

The requested resource
/upload.php
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided inthe request exceeds the capacity limit.
```

Comment: Could you kindly share your relevant piece of code?

Comment: I second that, code is needed. You are sending through ajax, but in GET or POST? My guess is that you are using GET and that would be the problem...

Comment: No @Salketer , I am using POST.

Comment: @19greg96 - I just attached the javascript code.

Comment: Base64 is roughly 37% bigger than source. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) Could it be that your file is just small enough to fit in max size but not its base64 version? What is your post_max_size?  and check it using phpinfo(), to make sure it is the real setting one.

Comment: @Salketer My server's post_max_size is 33MB. That way larger than 137% of the source file. I don't think post_max_size is the culprit here.

Comment: When you say it worked in iframe, is it with a file upload or with the toDataUrl data? Could you check the Content-Length reported by your browser for the post data? Does it give you the same error when you send a 1x1 canvas?

Comment: @Salketer - iframe with a file upload. The iframe upload which was successful had a content length 719949 but in case of todataURL, the content length was 1654610! For the record, the file size was 700KB.

Comment: Could it be possible you are using Suhosin?

Answer (score 2):

A `413 Request Entity Too Large` is normally generated when the client sends a POST request that is larger than what the server is capable of handling. This can be dependent on physical resources, or settings at different levels.

### Apache configuration

The limit in Apache is set via the LimitRequestBody directive and defaults to 0:

This directive specifies the number of bytes from 0 (meaning unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body.

Take a look at the full description of Apache's [LimitRequestBody directive.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

### PHP Configuration

In PHP, different limits are taking into account: `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` (if it is a file upload) and `memory_limit`.
`upload_max_filesize` has to be lower than `post_max_size`, which has to be lower than `memory_limit`.

### Suhosin

If PHP is running on Suhosin's protection, more configuration details can cause a server to reject a POST due to its size:

```
;suhosin.post.max_array_depth = 100
;suhosin.post.max_array_index_length = 64
;suhosin.post.max_name_length = 64
;suhosin.post.max_totalname_length = 256
;suhosin.post.max_value_length = 1000000
;suhosin.post.max_vars = 1000
```

Note that max_value_length here is exactly in the middle between the uploaded file size and the base64 version. So this might be the problem. Note that in configuration, the same lines appear for suhosin.get and suhosin.request. suhosin.request values should be equal or higher than get and post.